# Asynchronous task within scheduler in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, scheduler

I currently have a scheduled task within my Spring application.

However a two parts of this logic is severely time-consuming and I am wondering if there would be a way to make these two parts asynchronous so that it does not interfere with the time of the logic being executed.

The logic that I need to execute as follows.

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void startAuction() throws Exception {
        List<SchGoodsAuctionStartListRes> list = schedulerService.schGoodsAuctionStartList();

        for (SchGoodsAuctionStartListRes item : list) {
            schedulerService.schGoodsAuctionStart(item);

            // 1st time consuming block that needs async
            PushInfo pushInfo = pushMapper.pushGoodsSeller(item.getGoodsIdx());
            pushInfo.setTitle("Start");
            pushInfo.setBody("[" + pushInfo.getBrand() + "] started.");
            pushInfo.setPushGrp("001");
            pushInfo.setPushCode("003");
            fcmPushUtil.sendPush(pushInfo);

            // 2nd time consuming block that needs async
            List<PushInfo> pushInfos = pushMapper.pushGoodsAuctionAll(item.getIdx());
            for (PushInfo pushInfoItem : pushInfos) {
                pushInfoItem.setTitle("\uD83D\uDD14 open");
                pushInfoItem.setBody("[" + pushInfo.getBrand() + "] started. \uD83D\uDC5C");
                pushInfoItem.setPushGrp("002");
                pushInfoItem.setPushCode("008");
                fcmPushUtil.sendPush(pushInfoItem);
            }

        }
    }
```

From my understanding, a scheduler already is executing logic asynchronously, and I wonder if there would be any way of making those two blocks asynchronous so that it does not cause delays when executing this logic.

Comment: Add `@Async` and `@EnableAsync` so that it runs on a background thread instead of on the scheduling thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several approaches that you could take here.

### Configuring Thread Pool executor for Spring's scheduled tasks

By default Spring uses single thread executor to execute scheduled tasks, which means that even if you have multiple `@Scheduled` tasks or another execution for a task triggers before the previous one is completed, they will all have to wait in the queue.

You can configure your own executor to be used by Spring Scheduling. Take a look at the documentation of [`@EnableScheduling`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html), it is pretty exhaustive on the subject.

To configure `ExecutorService` to be used for scheduled tasks it is enough to define a bean:

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler  taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(8);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("task-scheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Additionally, if you use Spring Boot, you can use properties file:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=8
```

### Executing scheduled tasks asynchronously

To execute scheduled tasks asynchronously you can use Spring's `@Async` annotation (and make sure to `@EnableAsync` somewhere in your configuration. That will make your tasks to be executed on a background thread, freeing the scheduling thread.

```
@EnableAsync
public class ScheduledAsyncTask {

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void scheduleFixedRateTaskAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        // your task logic ...
    }
}
```

### Offload expensive parts of your tasks to a different executor

Finally, you could use a separate `ExecutorService` and run expensive parts of your tasks using that executor instead of the one used for task scheduling. This will keep the time needed to complete the execution on the thread used by Spring to schedule tasks to a minimum, allowing it to start next executions.

```
public class ScheduledAsyncTask implements DisposableBean {

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void scheduleFixedRateTaskAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            // Expensive calculations ...
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last one and the one before that are more or less the same although one uses Spring the other uses a manually managed executor. For the last one you are better of injecting an `AsyncTaskExecutor` which will be managed by Spring instead of manually trying to manage it (or simply don't use it and just use `@Async`).

Comment: @M.Deinum Agreed, one is probably better of using Spring-managed way in an actual application. I think there still may be some value in knowing how it can be done manually to better understand what Spring is doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive and intuitive feedback!! For clarification I should leave the startAuction method as it is and take out the two heavy task into a separate method with @EnableAsync and execute that in the startAuction method?

Comment: Separating the method and putting the @Async annotation worked! Thanks for your help

Comment: I am late to this thread, but I found [this simple example](https://medium.com/javarevisited/using-async-schedulers-in-spring-boot-78c15f9df466) quite good.